# R variable names: symbols/names or something else?

Tags: r, variables

Reading through the official R documentation as well as some of the contributed tutorials one learns that variable names are regarded as language objects - i.e. they are symbols aka names.

On p. 14 of the R Language Definition manual (version 3.1.1) under the heading of Symbol LookUp is a simple example: `"y <- 4  ... y is a symbol and 4 is its value"`.  What is confusing about this is that `is.symbol(y)`, or equivalently `is.name(y)`, return `FALSE` (for quoted and unquoted argument y).  When one coerces the variable into a symbol with `y <- as.name(4)`, then `is.symbol(y)` and `is.name(y)` return `TRUE`.  So it seems that variable names are not symbols/names until they are coerced into such.  What kind of R object is a variable name before it is coerced into a symbol?

Thanks for your help in clearing up this confusion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's important to understand what `is.symbol` and `is.name` are doing. First, they are really the same function. Observe that

```
is.symbol
# function (x)  .Primitive("is.symbol")
is.name
# function (x)  .Primitive("is.symbol")
```

so symbols/names are really the same thing in R. So here I will just use `is.name`

But also note that these functions are checking if the "thing" that the name you pass in points to is a symbol or a name. They are looking up what the name points to.

So if you did

```
# rm(foo)   make sure it doesn't exist
is.name(foo)
# Error: object 'foo' not found
```

you get an error. Despite the fact that `foo` is a name itself, what it points to is not yet defined. It's trying to "look-up" the value of `foo`. Observe that

```
quote(foo)
# foo
is.name(quote(foo))
# [1] TRUE
```

So `quote` will treat the parameter like a language object and you can test it that way. Now if we define `foo` to point to a name

```
(foo <- as.name("hello"))
# hello
is.name(foo)
# [1] TRUE
```

but if we point it to something else

```
(foo <- "hello")
# [1] "hello"
is.name(foo)
# [1] FALSE
is.character(foo)
# [1] TRUE
```

then it is no longer pointing to a name (here, it points to a character)

So variable names are names/symbols, but generally most R function will work with what they point to rather than return information about the name itself. So the problem was you were misinterpreting how `is.name` and `is.symbol` were working. It only really makes a difference when you are programming on the language.

Comment: What I would mention, is that `is.symbol` and `is.name` are exactly the same, _symbol_ and _name_ are just two different expressions for the same thing.

Comment: Aha.  Thanks, that explanation helps.  Regarding the example I cited from the R Language Definition manual p. 14: "y <- 4 ... y is a symbol and 4 is its value" would it be more accurate to say that identifier y is a symbol that points to a numeric. Hence is.symbol(y) is FALSE?

Comment: @nt54 I do think "y is a symbol that points to a numeric value of 4" is a better description than "y is a symbol and 4 is its value" but they are both basically the same. The "points to" relationship isn't really different than "having a value" in R. So I don't know if it's more accurate, but it may help form a better mental model of what's going on.